# 1/Infinite-norm condition number and the QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, condition-number, matrix-norms

I have seen that often the condition number of a matrix, $A$, may be estimated by taking the QR decomposition of $A$, $A=QR$, and using numerical methods to estimate the condition number of the upper triangular matrix $R$.

When using the definition of the condition number based on the 2-norm, i.e:

$\kappa_2(A)=||A||_2 ||A^{-1}||_2$

This makes sense to me, as:

$||A||_2=||QR||_2=||R||_2$ and $||A^{-1}||_2=||R^{-1}Q'||_2=||R^{-1}||_2$

(by the orthogonality of $Q$ and the fact the 2-norm is unaffected by multiplication by orthogonal matrices).

Therefore, $\kappa_2(A)=\kappa_2(R)$

However, this argument does not seem to hold for $\kappa_1$ or $\kappa_\infty$, the condition numbers based on the 1-norm and infinite-norm, as these norms are affected by multiplication of orthogonal matrices. So my question is:

When estimating $\kappa_1(A)$ or $\kappa_\infty(A)$, what is the logic in calculating $\kappa_1(R)$ or $\kappa_\infty(R)$? Is there some reason why $\kappa_1(A) \approx \kappa_1(R)$ and $\kappa_\infty(A) \approx \kappa_\infty(R)$?

As an example of when this is used, R's `kappa` and `rcond` functions estimate condition numbers for $R$ instead of $A$ when calculating the 1-norm and infinite-norm.

Comment: By using norm-equivalence, you can bound both $\kappa_1(A)$ and $\kappa_\infty(A)$ from above and below by using $\kappa_2(R)$. I don't know, why you would compute $\kappa_1(R)$ or $\kappa_\infty(R)$ with this in mind.

Comment: Ah I see, okay thank you! Do you have any idea how I could obtain these bounds explicitly to try and get an intuition as to whether this is a good approximation?

Also, if I understand correctly I believe the FORTAN matrix packages can calculate $||R^{-1}||_1$ much more quickly and efficiently than $||A^{-1}||_1$ as it is upper triangular and can use some form of backsolving, which is why using $R$ is more desirable than $A$, provided it is a reasonable approximation.